# python: sys is not defined

Tags: python, sys

I have a piece of code which is working in Linux, and I am now trying to run it in windows, I import sys but when I use sys.exit(). I get an error, sys is not defined. Here is the begining part of my code

```
try:
    import numpy as np
    import pyfits as pf
    import scipy.ndimage as nd
    import pylab as pl
    import os
    import heapq
    import sys
    from scipy.optimize import leastsq

except ImportError:
    print "Error: missing one of the libraries (numpy, pyfits, scipy, matplotlib)"
    sys.exit()
```

Why is sys not working??

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Move `import sys` *outside* of the `try`-`except` block:

```
import sys
try:
    # ...
except ImportError:
    # ...
```

If any of the imports *before* the `import sys` line fails, the *rest* of the block is not executed, and `sys` is never imported. Instead, execution jumps to the exception handling block, where you then try to access a non-existing name.

`sys` is a built-in module anyway, it is *always* present as it holds the data structures to track imports; if importing `sys` fails, you have bigger problems on your hand (as that would indicate that *all* module importing is broken).

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to import all of those modules at once. Even if one of them fails, the rest will not import. For example:

```
try:
    import datetime
    import foo
    import sys
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Let's say `foo` doesn't exist. Then only `datetime` will be imported.

What you can do is import the sys module at the beginning of the file, before the try/except statement:

```
import sys
try:
    import numpy as np
    import pyfits as pf
    import scipy.ndimage as nd
    import pylab as pl
    import os
    import heapq
    from scipy.optimize import leastsq

except ImportError:
    print "Error: missing one of the libraries (numpy, pyfits, scipy, matplotlib)"
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your code failed BEFORE import sys, so it can't find it when you handle the exception.

Also, you should indent the your code whithin the `try` block.

try:

```
import sys
# .. other safe imports
try:
    import numpy as np
    # other unsafe imports
except ImportError:
    print "Error: missing one of the libraries (numpy, pyfits, scipy, matplotlib)"
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers given above, check the last line of the error message in your console. In my case, the 'site-packages' path in sys.path.append('.....') was wrong.