# How to use a Github project in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I want to run a python notebook that is part of a project I downloaded from Github. When I run a .ipynb file I get an error:

```
import pickle
import warnings
from math import sqrt

import lightgbm as lgb
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd  # Basic library for all of our dataset operations
import pmdarima as pm
import tensorflow as tf
import xgboost as xgb
from bayes_opt import BayesianOptimization
from fbprophet import Prophet
from gluonts.dataset.common import ListDataset
from gluonts.evaluation.backtest import make_evaluation_predictions
from gluonts.model.deepar import DeepAREstimator
from gluonts.mx.trainer import Trainer
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model, svm
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, cross_val_score
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AR
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA, ARMA
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing, SimpleExpSmoothing
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX
from tqdm import tqdm

from utils.metrics import evaluate
```

This is the error I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-b033063c2c35> in <module>
     29 from tqdm import tqdm
     30 
---> 31 from utils.metrics import evaluate

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.metrics'
```

I tried to apply the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761697/python-sys-is-not-defined) but it doesn't work for me.

This is how the folder containing the code looks like, the code above is from `02-Forecasting_models.ipynb`:

[image]

If anyone has any idea as to how I can solve this, I would be very grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you start the jupyter notebook from a different location. The current directory is different from the one where the project is. At the file beginning, try to call

```py
import os
os.chdir("directory of your project")
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your solution and added `os.chdir()` with the main folder and the subfolders inside it. However, it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @SaïdMaanan may you share the repository link?

Comment: Yes, sure. Here it is: https://github.com/jiwidi/time-series-forecasting-with-python

Comment: @PatrikVolkovic Sorry for disturbing you again, but did you have a look at the github repository?